# Convert special chars to HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.html = '&lt;script&gt;';
```

I know that PHP has the ability to convert `&lt;script&gt;` to `<script>` but can Javascript do the same?

Comment: Does this help, using `ng-bind-html`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: try to use replace method

Comment: @christiandev `ng-bind-html` does not automatically bind unsafe values as html.  You would need to create a filter that tells angular it is safe to interpret the html values.  There used to be `ng-html-bind-unsafe` but it has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this works

```
function escapeSpecialChars(text) {
    return text
        .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
        .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
        .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
        .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a filter that uses the `$sce` service. [*$sce reference*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

```
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

`$sce` stands for 'Strict Contextual Escaping` it has a method that tells angular to trust text as html.

You can then bind the value to an element and by using the filter it will display html.

```
<span ng-bind-html="foo | unsafe"></span>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/dz2z2b79/)**